# Hide content depending on password

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

So what I'm trying to do, is to have three categories, which should only be shown if a visitor on my site writes a certain password. So no need for users database. I just want the different categories to be accessible only when the right password is typed in.

I've tried with many different plugins, as I'm not really familiar with the back end.

Comment: You've tagged wordpress, which complicates things more than a flat PHP project would. You also have given no architectural information. We need more.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate passwords with an account type. According on account type with php condition you can choose what you want to display.

If you want more informations, explain more your issue.

Have fun :)